# Vary symbology of points by proximity

Tags: arcpy, symbology, arcgis-pro, proximity

I have 1,000 point locations that represent hospitals, and I want them to be symbolized as different colored points. Since a map reader isn't going to tell the difference between 30 shades of red or blue, I can't have the same colors for neighboring points. Neighboring points, which represent different hospitals would imply the same organization or hospital institution (which isn't the case). What I've tried is using the Near tool in ArcGIS Pro to find the closest point for each point and what the distance is to it. Where I'm stalled is applying a staggered symbology, so that points within, say, 20-30 miles aren't given the same color.

I've also explored trying this with Python where I iterate through each feature point, use a buffer to define the area that I don't want to repeat the symbology, then apply a symbology, and move on to the next point. I'm not sure this is the correct path.

Does anyone have any other ideas for applying symbology based on proximity of features to each other?

Comment: Why not just use Unique values and add 1000 random colors?

Comment: Because that won't control for adding the same color to nearby points. I do not want neighboring points to have the same color; it will confuse people.

Comment: So your goal is a legend with unique 1000 colors? this would each hospital would have its own color, right?

Comment: Correct, but a restriction on proximity/neighbors. I don't want points that are close by to have the same color